# Reset download state of start screen tiles in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, tiles

After installing Windows 8.1 a while ago, I noticed that a lot of the apps that I have downloaded and installed on the computer still show the "Install" icon in the lower right hand side of the tile, and in the "All Apps" view.

Notice how apps that I have installed (as in, launching them opens the app, not the Store) like Calendar, Reading List, Skype, Mail, Music, and News still show a little "download" indicator at the bottom right:
[image: Calendar, Reading List, Skype, Mail, Music, and News showing the download indicator]
And it's not just a problem with the tiles, Windows really does seem to think that they're not installed, because in the All Apps view it still asks to "Install" the app (here's a snipping of the M section in my All Apps view, notice how Mail asks to "Install"):

[image: Mail app asking to install]

Resetting things like App Licenses in the Store (or using WSReset) doesn't help, and I can't seem to find any reason for only a few of my apps to do this. Has anyone else encountered anything like this, or know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Windows Store. Right click or swipe down, go to your Apps and just install them. The upgrade keeps your apps as a placeholder you just have to install them again basically. One easy step.

Comment: The apps are already installed, the Start Screen just shows them as uninstalled. I can launch the apps just fine